# Close the session in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I close the session after the user successfully logged in?

When the user successfully logs in, he is doing his operations, but in back end the admin deactivates the user. At that time close the user session and redirect to the login page.

Is this possible in rails devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a before_action on your application controller, something like:

```
before_action :check_inactive_user, if: :current_user

def check_inactive_user
  if current_user.inactive?
    current_user.sign_out
    redirect_to root_path, flash: {notice: 'Your user is inactive'}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks arieljuod its wokr's for me

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` utilizes sessions so you can do `reset_session` in any controller action to bring them back to the login screen.

Comment: you are saying use before action  filter in every controller right?

Comment: I tried reset_session working fine, but if in case admin session is  opened in same browser admin session also reseting